# AWS Ec2 postgres \copy...: permission denied

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an aws ec2 instance that is running postgres on it. I have a file in the same instance that is a csv file so that I can populate the database. When I go into postgres to run the copy file, it is saying that the permission is denied. I am accessing the postgress shell with a superuser. I am not sure why I am getting a permission denied. Here is a screen shot of what I am running and error I am getting.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting up file permissions using chmod for the .CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what OS user has launched `psql`, but presumably it's `postgres`.

It doesn't have the right to read any file inside `/home/ec2-user` because this directory has permissions `drwx------`, meaning that only `ec2-user` or `root` can look into it (the fact that the CSV file itself has world-wide read permissions is not sufficient, all directories in the hierarchy must have the `x` bit set to allow traversal).

The most common solutions:

1) `chmod 755 /home/ec2-user` so postgres can access it.

2) Launch `psql` under the `ec2-user` with an explicit `-U` option to specify a database user. This may also mean that a password is going to be asked, depending on Postgres authentication rules set in `pg_hba.conf`. You may also edit these rules if you're an admin and they don't match your needs.

3) Put the CSV data files in a dedicated directory that both `ec2-user` and `postgres` can read, so typically that would be outside of any `/home` directory.